# Not able to get HTML TAG TEXT using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am facing a strange behavior in webdriver. The problem is very simple. I just want to print the names of the text in the drop down but I am not able to do that, I have tried various ways.

**WAY 1:** Using `getText` with my code snippet

```
List<WebElement> dupmap =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a"));
System.out.println("Size of sub menu is : " + dupmap.size());
for(int j=0;j<dupmap.size();j++){
System.out.println("Sub menu options are : " + dupmap.get(i).getText());
}
```

Getting null as output.

**WAY 2:** Using `.getAttribute("innerText")` output as `Load saved data source`

```
System.out.println("Sub menu options are : " + dupmap.get(i).getAttribute("innerText"));}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this `Load saved data source` as output.

**WAY 3:** Using `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` output as `Load saved data source <span class="caret-right"></span>`; not sure what is this?

**WAY 4:** Using `.getAttribute("textContent")` output as `Load saved data source`; not sure what is this?

But when I change my xpath from this `//*[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a` to `//*[@class='dropdown-menu']` and then use .getText(); I am getting output as

```
Size of sub menu is : 6
Sub menu options are : Add map...
Duplicate
Rename
Auto-align map objects...
Analyze territory alignment...
Optimize selected territories...
Remove...
Sub menu options are : Add map...
Duplicate
Rename
Auto-align map objects...
Analyze territory alignment...
Optimize selected territories...
Remove...
Sub menu options are : Add map...
Duplicate
Rename
Auto-align map objects...
Analyze territory alignment...
Optimize selected territories...
Remove...
Sub menu options are : Add map...
Duplicate
Rename
Auto-align map objects...
Analyze territory alignment...
Optimize selected territories...
Remove...
Sub menu options are : Add map...
Duplicate
Rename
Auto-align map objects...
Analyze territory alignment...
Optimize selected territories...
Remove...
Sub menu options are : Add map...
Duplicate
Rename
Auto-align map objects...
Analyze territory alignment...
Optimize selected territories...
Remove...
```

Desired text but as you can see all menu options are together and in iteration of 6. I am not sure what is happening. My menu and its source code are:

[image]

and the menu is:

[image]

Also when I try to click one of the options I am getting error as element not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int j=0;j<dupmap.size();j++){
  System.out.println("Sub menu options are : " + dupmap.get(i).getText());
}
```

In your code, you used `dupmap.get(i).getText()`. but inside for loop you have used `j` as index variable.

Comment: @rajNishKuMar Welcome:)